# Posting byte message in solace queue through jmeter

Tags: post, jmeter, message, solace

Need to post a byte message to solace queue using Jmeter. I have tried in following manner might be am incorrect but tried with following:

1. Use JMSPublisher sampler
2. create jndi.properties file and put in jmeter/lib

jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial = com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = smf://<remote IP and port>
java.naming.security.principal=<username>
java.naming.security.credentials=<password>
 Solace_JMS_VPN=<VPN Name>
```

in JMSPublisher sampler (in GUI)

Connection Factory = connectionFactory

Destination = (Queue Name )

Message Type (radio button---Byte message)

Content encoding -- RAW

in text area ---> (Byte message)

Note : I have used actual values of IP/port/username/port/queuename/bytemessage, cannot share those. Soljms jar is available in lib folder too.

getting error :

Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: JNDI lookup failed - 503: Service Unavailable [Root exception is (null)  com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 503: Service Unavailable]

Though it is working perfectly fine when did with java spring boot. There used properties files in place of JNDI.

It would be great if anyone can guide me , please do not give activeMQ JNDI  am actively looking for posting on solace queue or create connection to solace appliances through Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be putting your `Byte message` into the textarea as it accepts either plain text or an [XStream](https://x-stream.github.io/) object, consider providing your payload via binary file(s) instead

If you're capable of sending the message using Java code you should be able to replicate the same using:

1. JMeter's [JSR223 Sampler with Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) (Java syntax will work)
2. Or [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) sampler if you need "strict" java

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for quick response . I"ll try with what you have mentioned .

Comment: Sorry for late response. As new to groovy , took some time. Thanks Dmitri JSR223 sampler with groovy works perfect. Best part of the groovy it supports java. Take care of respective .jars which should be available in jmeter/lib folder.